# How to generalize serve of tarpc service

Tags: generics, rust

I'm relatively new to Rust. We have to use `tarpc` for a simple implementation of the Google FS. We have 3 traits decorated with `#[tarpc::service]`. For example:

```
#[tarpc::service]
pub trait Master {
    async fn lookup(url: String) -> SocketAddr;
}

impl Master for GfsMaster {...}
```

I don't want to duplicate a whole lot of code when serving these 3 services so I wanted to create a generalized function that takes in the `SocketAddr` to listen to and the serve instance to execute. I looked into `Channel::execute` to see what requirements I have to fulfill

```
fn execute<S>(self, serve: S) -> impl Stream<Item = impl Future<Output = ()>>
where
    Self: Sized,
    S: Serve<Req = Self::Req, Resp = Self::Resp> + Clone,
{
    self.requests().execute(serve)
}
```

and came up with this function:

```
async fn serve_rpc_service<C, S>(addr: SocketAddr, serve: S) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
    where
        C: Channel + Sized,
        S: Serve<Req = C::Req, Resp = C::Resp> + Clone,
{
    let mut listener = listen(addr, Json::default).await?;
    listener.config_mut().max_frame_length(usize::MAX);

    listener
        .filter_map(|r| ready(r.ok()))
        .map(server::BaseChannel::with_defaults)
        .map(|channel| {
            channel
                .execute(serve.clone())
                .for_each(|future| async {
                    spawn_local(Box::pin(future));
                })
        })
        .buffer_unordered(10)
        .for_each(|_| async {})
        .await;

    Ok(())
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
serve_master_task(SocketAddr::new(server_ip, port), Master::serve(gfs_master.clone()))
```

For some reason, I get the error that the traits `serialize` and `deserialize` are not satisfied. I could not figure out where the requirements of these traits come from. I added:

```
<C as Channel>::Req: Deserialize<'a>,
<C as Channel>::Resp: Serialize
```

and changed `async fn serve_rpc_service<C, S>` to `async fn serve_rpc_service<'a, C, S>`. Now I get this error:

```
error: implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
   --> src\lib.rs:108:4
    |
108 | /             channel
109 | |                 .execute(serve.clone())
    | |_______________________________________^ implementation of `Deserialize` is not general enough
    |
    = note: `ClientMessage<<C as tarpc::server::Channel>::Req>` must implement `Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
    = note: ...but it actually implements `Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I don't know what to do anymore. Why can't I just forward the serve instance using the same type-parameter conditions that execute uses?

Comment: The code snippet is not complete, as the actual definition of the type or value you pass to `fn serve_rpc_service` as the generic parameter `serve: S` is necessary to check the compilation error, which includes your detailed implementation of `Deserialize` trait.

Comment: @rustyhu I added some more information but that's everything I have. Most of the code is generated by this attribute macro `#[tarpc::service]` including the `ServeMaster<Self>` returned by `Master::serve`